# Using a for loop to run class methods from multiple class objects in Java

Tags: java, class, object, methods, hashmap

(for some context) My real world problem is that I have many `Text` objects that depending on conditions will need the method `text.setText("sometext")` to be executed. (Im creating a calendar that as the months change, so does the first day of the month, which in turn causes the dates (1,31) to change where they appear on the calendar interface i created .

My approach was to create `Text` objects, add them to a HashMap. Then, depending on where the first day of the month is, call the appropriate `Text` objects from the HashMap and run a method from within the `Text` class `text.setText("sometext")`

i haven't added the actual code, because 99% is irrelevant and would probably just confuse issues but this code should illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.  `public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExampleCLass object1 = new ExampleCLass("object1");
    ExampleCLass object2 = new ExampleCLass("object2");

    HashMap<Integer, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    //if some condition has been met
    for(Object object : hashMap){
        object.printname();
    }

}
```

}`

```
public class ExampleCLass {

private final String name;


public ExampleCLass(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void printName(){
    System.out.println(this.name);
}
```

}

any tips on getting this to work, or suggestions of a different/better approach would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting your code, which didn't even compile, to work.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class HashMapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HashMapTest().test();
    }

    public void test() {
        HashMap<Integer, ExampleClass> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        ExampleClass object1 = new ExampleClass("object1");
        hashMap.put(1, object1);
        ExampleClass object2 = new ExampleClass("object2");
        hashMap.put(2, object2);

        // if some condition has been met
        Set<Integer> hashSet = hashMap.keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> iter = hashSet.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Integer key = iter.next();
            ExampleClass ec = hashMap.get(key);
            System.out.println(ec.printName());
        }
    }

    public class ExampleClass {

        private final String name;

        public ExampleClass(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String printName() {
            return this.name;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Gilbert Le Blanc. I was able to use and modify your solution in my code. Sorry about not explaining in question that the code did not compile. I used it as an example in order to explain what i meant.